# deploy nodejs to heroku

Tags: git, node.js, deployment, heroku

I've followed the getting started guide to deploy a nodejs application to heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

It worked fine until `git push heroku master`. This terminated with the following output:

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1018, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (894/894), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1018/1018), 4.03 MiB | 64 KiB/s, done.
Total 1018 (delta 75), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.6.20
       Using npm version: 1.0.106
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm


       > ws@0.4.21 install /tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
       > node install.js

       [ws v0.4.21] Attempting to compile blazing fast native extensions.
       [ws v0.4.21] Native code compile failed (but the module will still work):
       [ws v0.4.21] The native extensions are faster, but not required.
       [ws v0.4.21] On Windows, native extensions require Visual Studio and Python.
       [ws v0.4.21] On Unix, native extensions require Python, make and a C++ compiler.
       [ws v0.4.21] Start npm with --ws:verbose to show compilation output (if any).

       > hiredis@0.1.14 preinstall /tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis
       > make || gmake

       cd deps/hiredis && make static
       make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/deps/hiredis'
       make[1]: Nothing to be done for `static'.
       make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/deps/hiredis'
       node-waf configure build
       Setting srcdir to                        : /tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis 
       Setting blddir to                        : /tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build 
       Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
       Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
       Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
       Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
       Checking for g++                         : ok  
       Checking for node path                   : not found 
       Checking for node prefix                 : ok /tmp/node-node-Wyfk 
       'configure' finished successfully (0.029s)
       Waf: Entering directory `/home/lhk/Desktop/zwillenhomepage/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build'
       Waf: Leaving directory `/home/lhk/Desktop/zwillenhomepage/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build'
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/node-waf", line 16, in <module>
           Scripting.prepare(t, os.getcwd(), VERSION, wafdir)
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 145, in prepare
           prepare_impl(t, cwd, ver, wafdir)
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 135, in prepare_impl
           main()
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 188, in main
           fun(ctx)
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 386, in build
           return build_impl(bld)
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 405, in build_impl
           bld.compile()
         File "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Build.py", line 268, in compile
           os.chdir(self.bldnode.abspath())
       OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/lhk/Desktop/zwillenhomepage/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build'
       make: *** [all] Error 1
       sh: gmake: not found
       npm ERR! hiredis@0.1.14 preinstall: `make || gmake`
       npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make || gmake"` failed with 127
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the hiredis@0.1.14 preinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hiredis package,
       npm ERR! not with npm itself.
       npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
       npm ERR!     make || gmake
       npm ERR! You can get their info via:
       npm ERR!     npm owner ls hiredis
       npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-Wyfk/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-Rq2Y/cli.js" "rebuild"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54
       npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_ngyi26sy7e54/npm-debug.log
       npm not ok
 !     Failed to rebuild dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:morning-plateau-9747.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-plateau-9747.git'
```

I don't know how to fix this. The application is still a barebone. I decided to get it up and running on heroku and then incrementally add the features I wanted. It runs great on localhost, npm installs all the dependencies without an error and with a Procfile it even works with foreman. I've used github to create the repo and cloned it on my machine. Deploying to my github account works without problems. Here's the link to the repo https://github.com/lhk/zwillenhomepage

What can I do ?

Relevant package.json:

```
{
  "name": "zwillen-webseite",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "server.js"
  },
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.x",
    "socket.io": "0.9.8",
    "jade": "0.27.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the hiredis module in context is being used by socket.io.

If you refer to the thread mentioned in eis' answer, you'd see that both of you are using socket.io 0.9.8.

Try using 0.9.6 (I use it on heroku and have never had such problems).

Comment: Quite odd. I had the same error with socket.io 0.9.10, downgrading to 0.9.6 fixed it. Thanks! According to this https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1030 they've removed redis in a recent commit, so that error should go away soon.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `node_modules/hiredis` from source control by adding it to your `.gitignore` file. See the full answer at [socket.io + node.js on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674550/socket-io-node-js-on-heroku/15427146#15427146)

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is trying to compile hiredis and failing. Is this intentional, do you need it? Do you have a reference to hiredis in your app? If so, that might be the culprit. If not, I'd try contacting Heroku support.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674550/socket-io-node-js-on-heroku).